# PHP very small decimals result in error

Tags: php, floating-point, decimal, floating-accuracy

PHP is erroring out on me when working with small decimals / floats. Take the following code:

```
$spotPrices['entry'] = 1.6591;
$price['o'] = 1.65908;

$currentresult = $spotPrices['entry'] - $price['o'];

echo $currentresult;
```

I would expect this to output `0.00002` (the answer). But instead it outputs: `-1.99999999999E-5`

Why is it doing this and, more importantly, how can I get the correct result?

---

I've done some searching on the forums and seen that floating points give PHP fits but haven't seen a solution or workaround that seems to answer my question.

Comment: You have made a typo, $spotPrice vs $spotPrices

Comment: If you need precision with floats, you should look into a high precision library such as bcmath or just don't work with floats (convert to an integer, i.e. value * 10000 and change on display). http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My calculator is saying that the result should be 0.00002

use number_format:

```
$currentresult = number_format($spotPrices['entry'] - $price['o'], 8);
```

Comment: using number_format worked for my application, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 0.00002 you get 1.9999999999909E-5 which is 0.000019999999999909. This is due to floating point precision. Precision is platform-dependent. You can read up on it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: but he is getting - 1.9999999999909E-5 so i think he is showing us a different code

Comment: I assumed it was a typo. I copied his code and I get a positive number.